# What does 1 represent on MaximumResponseHeadersLength?

Tags: c#, http, httprequest

When using `MaximumResponseHeadersLength` on a HTTP request in C# what does `1` represent?

I understand `-1` is no limit.

e.g.

```
httpRequest.MaximumResponseHeadersLength = 1;
```

Comment: 1 = 1024 bytes (1 KB), remember default is 64 (=64 KB).

Comment: As described on the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.maximumresponseheaderslength%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): "The length, in kilobytes (1024 bytes), of the response headers."

Comment: 1 simply means max 1 KB header length, it doesn't have a special meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it is stated [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.maximumresponseheaderslength%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), `MaximumResponseHeadersLength`:

> Gets or sets the maximum allowed length of the response headers.
>
> The length, in kilobytes (1024 bytes), of the response headers.

Furthermore,

> The length of the response header includes the response status line and any extra control characters that are received as part of HTTP protocol. A value of -1 means no limit is imposed on the response headers; a value of 0 means that all requests fail.

So in the following assignment:

```
httpRequest.MaximumResponseHeadersLength = 1;
```

We set the maximum length of response headers to 1 KB.

Comment: I don't understand why you've received 2 down-votes here. They're useless without an explanation. +1.

Comment: @DeeMac I can't get it also. However, this don't surprise me, since it's the classic behavior of some users of SO, where they downvote, without provide the poster of the question or answer with a hint where is wrong and what should correct. Thank you !

Comment: +1 from me too, answer shows research and is good quality. Odd behaviour from the downvoters.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti thank you both for you comment and your edit !